# comments reply script not working

Tags: comments, comment-form

Sadly my "reply" link for threaded comments is not working.

#### The current situation:

First i load the comments reply script (check if scripts content load: works) into the `<head>` using two functions (the first `wp_register_script()` at the init hook, the second `wp_print_scripts()` at the wp_head hook):

Then i add the Reply link:

```
comment_reply_link( 
     array( 
         'reply_text'   => __( 'Reply', OXO_TEXTDOMAIN )
        ,'depth'        => isset( $args['args']['depth'] ) ? $args['args']['depth'] : (int) 3
        ,'max_depth'    => isset( $args['args']['max_depth'] ) ? $args['args']['max_depth'] : (int) 5
     )
    ,get_comment_ID()
    ,$post->ID
);
```

which produces this html-output (example)

```
<a onclick="return addComment.moveForm("comment-11", "11", "respond", "149")" href="/wordpress/?p=149&cpage=2&replytocom=11#respond" class="comment-reply-link">Reply</a>
```

**I got everything according to any recommendation i read:**

My comments are within a `<div id="comments">` and the comments form above it within a `<div id="respond">`.

I still get dropped to the #respond-anchor and the comment form above the comments (`http://localhost/wordpress/?p=149&cpage=2&replytocom=11#respond`), instead of getting the comment form displayed below the comment i want to reply to.

#### What may i do wrong?

Google, tutorials, how-to and else were so far of no help. Everything seems to be according to the recommended standard...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't link the script file directly. Enqueue it instead, e.g. in `functions.php`:

```
function mytheme_enqueue_comment_reply() {
    // on single blog post pages with comments open and threaded comments
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) { 
        // enqueue the javascript that performs in-link comment reply fanciness
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); 
    }
}
// Hook into wp_enqueue_scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_comment_reply' );
```

You can also do this, in the document head, prior to the `wp_head()` call:

```
<?php
// on single blog post pages with comments open and threaded comments
if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) { 
    // enqueue the javascript that performs in-link comment reply fanciness
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); 
}
?>
```

EDIT:

Hooking into `wp_head`, rather than e.g. `wp_print_scripts`, is important. The `wp_print_scripts` does not work in the same way that `wp_print_styles` does, to output stylesheet links.

So: if you're using `wp_print_scripts`, change the hook to `wp_head`.

EDIT 2:

Based on your pastebin-linked code, have you tried the following, to rule out potential issues?

1. Remove callback function from `wp_comment_list()`
2. Move `wp_comment_list()` call to *before* `comment_form()` call
3. Remove the argument array from `comment_form()`

I don't know that any of those will solve your problem, but they may help us track down its origin.

Comment: @Cip Bennet - Thanks for the answer. Sadly that's close to what I'm doing: First I `wp_register_script()` at the init hook and then `wp_print_scripts()` on the wp_head hook. As i wrote: It get's loaded, but it doesn't work (and I'm really not good with JS).

Comment: `wp_print_scripts` doesn't work in the same way that `wp_print_styles` works. You need to use `wp_head` directly.

Comment: I tried all ways now multiple times. The script gets loaded fine, the reply link gets rendered as written in the Q, but i still get dropped to the `#respond` anchor instead of getting the textarea right beneath the comment i want to reply to. So far i think it's not the script itself, more the way the script interacts with the mark-up. My problem is that i don't know what exactly the script does on which element. Maybe you could add some comments to help me understand better? It's pretty confusing aith all the a,b,c,d.. Thanks in advance! :) http://pastebin.com/rKW00JzH

Comment: Are you using the `comment_form()` function to generate the comment-reply form markup? If not, can you post your markup?

Comment: The only thing out-of-the-ordinary I see there is that your comment-reply form comes before the comment list, though I can't imagine why that should matter. See troubleshooting edits to answer, above.

Comment: Thanks Chip, the "troubleshooting guide" was helpfull. It tracked down the problem to my callback function (never thought this could be). I'll post back in some minutes. :)

Comment: Hey Chip, thanks for anything. For some reason, the reply link is different from the TwentyTen onclick event: Missing the leading `div-`: `onclick="return addComment.moveForm("comment-21", "21", "respond", "149")"`... I can't get behind why this is happening with my callback, but it's working now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! This was a tricky one.

Comment: If you hook into `'comment_form_before'` you can drop the check for `comments_open()` and the script will be enqueued in the footer.